# SublimeLinter: modules phpcs and phpmd not working

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimelinter, phpmd, phpcs

in `Sublime Text 3` I have installed via the `Package Manager` following packages:

- SublimeLinter
- SublimeLinter-phpmd
- SublimeLinter-phpcs
- and few others..

The problem is that neither `phpmd` or `phpcs` are working. When opening a `php` file in ST3 and then clicking: `ctrl` and ` I get following debug info:

```
SublimeLinter: debug mode: on 
SublimeLinter: temp directory: c:\users\alekspav\appdata\local\temp\SublimeLinter3-alekspav 
SublimeLinter: annotations activated: <builtin> 
SublimeLinter: json activated: <builtin> 
SublimeLinter: WARNING: phpcs deactivated, cannot locate 'phpcs' 
SublimeLinter: annotations activated: <builtin> 
SublimeLinter: WARNING: jshint deactivated, cannot locate 'jshint' 
SublimeLinter: php activated: C:\xampp\php\php.exe 
SublimeLinter: WARNING: phpmd deactivated, cannot locate 'phpmd'
SublimeLinter: WARNING: htmltidy deactivated, cannot locate 'tidy' 
SublimeLinter: WARNING: csslint deactivated, cannot locate 'csslint' 
SublimeLinter: php: submitter.php ['C:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe', '-l', '-n', '-d', 'display_errors=On', '-d', 'log_errors=Off'] 
SublimeLinter: php output:
No syntax errors detected in -
```

I am particularry interested in these 2 lines:

- SublimeLinter: WARNING: phpcs deactivated, cannot locate '**phpcs**'
- SublimeLinter: WARNING: phpmd deactivated, cannot locate '**phpmd**'

What I tried to do to fix the problem is to edit users config file:
`Sublime text 3: Preferences -> package settings -> sublime linter-> settings - user`

And then added `cmd` key as following:

```
    "phpcs": {
        "@disable": false,
        "args": [],
        "cmd": "C:/xampp/htdocs/web/vendor/bin/phpcs/",
        "excludes": [],
        "standard": "PSR2"
    },
    "phpmd": {
        "@disable": false,
        "args": [],
        "cmd": "C:/xampp/htdocs/web/vendor/bin/phpmd/",
        "excludes": [],
        "rulesets": "cleancode,codesize,controversial,design,naming,unusedcode"
    }
```

As you have guessed - this didn't resolve the issue. I also tried to write path without / at the end and also tried to use \ delimeter instead of /. And I also tried to specify PFAM file directly.. And also tried to use ${project} variable rather than whole C:/ path. I am still getting warnings after ST3 restart.

My other question would be - how to output "${project}" directory in debug window? Because I am not sure it is set correctly so I want to test it.

More info:

Sublime project directory is: `C:\xampp\htdocs\web\test.sublime-project`

Here are  `phpmd` and `phpcs` installations:

- "C:\xampp\htdocs\web\vendor\bin\phpcs\phpcbf.phar"
- "C:\xampp\htdocs\web\vendor\bin\phpcs\phpcs.phar"
- "C:\xampp\htdocs\web\vendor\bin\phpmd\phpmd.phar"

**Edit:**

Seems like I was doing it wrong. I have added a `composer.json` into project directory with following contents:

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "2.*",
        "phpmd/phpmd" : "@stable",
        "mongodb/mongodb" : "@dev"
    }
}
```

After installing everything with `composer install` command - I got `vendor` folder created for me with lots of directories inside, including the `bin` folder. It has all the necessary files now, but I am still getting the same error. Modules could not be found for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay,

I am not sure if it's a bug or a feature, but I found the solution to the problem.

1. First - you have to install `phpcs` and `phpmd` using the `pear`! Without this - you will see the warnings from initial post.

> phpcs: **pear install PHP_CodeSniffer**
>
> phpmd: instructions here: http://pear.phpmd.org/ (I do not remember the name of another repository but during the first installation you will encounter the error that some lib is missing and you will be prompted with a text to add one more repository which has missing dependencies for phpmd pear installation. All easy)

Start `ST3` and check. No edits in configuration are necessary. Both modules should be working in `Sublime Text 3`! But we are now using the `pear` modules instead of `composer` modules. My initial idea was to use the `conmposer`. It is much easier to mantain and update.

In case you are not familliar with it - google. In project directory you should have a file called `composer.json` with the content similar to:

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer":    "2.*",
        "phpmd/phpmd" :                 "@stable"
    }
}
```

Then go and install all modules using the `Windows command prompt` with `composer install` command

2. As adressed in intiail post - in user config of `SublimeLinter` use the following config:

   ```
       "phpcs": {
           "@disable": false,
           "args": [],
           "cmd": "${project}/vendor/bin/phpcs.bat",
           "excludes": [],
           "standard": "${project}/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/CodeSniffer/Standards/PSR2/ruleset.xml"
       },
       "phpmd": {
           "@disable": false,
           "args": [],
           "cmd": "${project}/vendor/bin/phpmd.bat",
           "excludes": [],
           "rulesets": "cleancode,codesize,controversial,design,naming,unusedcode"
       }
   ```

Now restart `Sublime test 3` and turn on debugging and open `PHP` file. Result is:

```
reloading plugin SublimeLinter-phpcs.linter
SublimeLinter: phpcs linter loaded 
reloading plugin SublimeLinter-phpmd.linter
SublimeLinter: phpmd linter loaded 
...
reloading settings Packages/User/SublimeLinter.sublime-settings
SublimeLinter: phpcs activated: C:\xampp\php\phpcs.bat 
SublimeLinter: phpmd activated: C:\xampp\php\phpmd.bat 
...
SublimeLinter: phpcs: index.php ['C:/xampp/htdocs/web/vendor/bin/phpcs.bat', '--report=checkstyle', '--standard=C:/xampp/htdocs/web/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/CodeSniffer/Standards/PSR2/ruleset.xml'] 
SublimeLinter: phpcs output:
.. errors in PHP file listed
Package Control: Skipping automatic upgrade, last run at 2016-09-05 17:12:20, next run at 2016-09-05 18:12:20 or after
...
SublimeLinter: phpmd: index.php ['C:/xampp/htdocs/web/vendor/bin/phpmd.bat', '@', 'text', 'cleancode,codesize,controversial,design,naming,unusedcode'] 
SublimeLinter: phpmd output:
.. errors in PHP file listed
```

As you can see - `SublimeLinter` first loads the `pear` `bat`s in `PHP` directory! But when submitting the `PHP` file for analysis - it is using the new `bat`s in project directory.

My explanation is that `SublimeLinter` always needs `pear` `phpcs` and `phpmd` to be installed before using `composer` equivalents. This is quite stupid, if you ask me.. but I couldn't find any other solution.

Comment: well, I think the issue will be resolved if you just add `BIN` folder path into the `PATH` environment variable.. The idea is that `SublimeLinter` is not looking for the "cmd" parameter during the first initiation. It fails to find the `bat` files in `PHP` directory because without `pear` installation of `phpcs` and `phpmd` - there will be no such files. So If you tell him "hey, look into this folder" - it should identify files in `BIN` folder instead. Anyway, I am happy with my first aproach and don't want to break anything :)

Comment: It's strange that I can't edit my own post.. Anyway, I was thinking that the issue can also be resolved by creating a symbolic link to `PHP` folder as well. I mean the `shortcut` of bat to `PHP` directory.. But not tested, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I also had hard time trying to get sublimeLinter-phpmd work. here is how I fixed it:

Assumes:

- you're on windows
- you have sublime-text 3 and sublimeLinter installed

Steps:

1. install pear:http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php
2. **important**: add pear directory into $PATH
3. install phpmd using pear **under your pear directory**: https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-phpmd
4. restart sublime-text 3.

For me, it's because I missed step 2 so that phpmd linter won't work.

There is no need to install per-project phpmd using composer. and there is no need to manually modify SublimeLinter's setting after installed SublimeLinter-phpmd.

May this help.